# Fastest way to check if a string has 3 or more groups of numbers

Tags: php

So basically I need to check if a string has 3 or more groups of separated digits, example:

```
words1 words2 111 222 333      //> YES, it has 3 groups of digits (separated by space)

words 1 2                      //> NO

words 2011 words2 2012 2013    //> YES
```

I was thinking something like

```
preg_match('/(\b\d+\b){3,}/',$string)
```

But it's not working at all (always return false)

Thansk to @Basti i am using this regex now:

```
'/(\D*\d+\D*){3,}/'
```

Comment: Have you tried the solution you've come up with? If so, what doesn't work about it?

Comment: Since you know what your delimiters look like, how about `explode()`?

Comment: you could use explode and then check the array parts to see if they are integers and count em.

Comment: Well, benchmark the two approaches.

Comment: This sort of question would get a much more favorable reception from the Code Review stackexchange; that said, I am surprised this has received so many down votes.

Comment: Even I don't understand the unnecessary downvotes (may be because of wrong syntax of preg_match in OP). I upvoted the question but I could upvote only once :(

Comment: @yes123: Your answer (\D*\d+\D*){3,} even matches text 'word1 word2 word3' not sure that's how you wanted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression is saying "Find one or more digits at least three times". What you actually want is: "Find two or more digits surrounded by something I don't care about at least three times.":

```
preg_match("/(\D*\d{2,}\D*){3,}/", $string)
```

The problem with your expression is that you are not allowing anything other than digits and word bounds.

Test: `var_dump(preg_match('/(\D*\d{2,}\D*){3,}/',$string, $match), $match);` on your three strings.

```
int 1
array
  0 => string ' 111 222 333' (length=12)
  1 => string '333' (length=3)
int 0
array
  empty
int 1
array
  0 => string ' 2012 2013' (length=10)
  1 => string '13' (length=2)
```

---

yes123 note:

I am using this function I wrote, it can check for any numbers of groups:

```
function countDigits($haystack) {
    preg_match_all('/\b\d+\b/',$haystack,$matches);
    return count($matches[0]);
}

echo countDigits('2011 abc 2012'); //> prints 2
```

Comment: +1, but in this case your `\D` and mine `\b` aren't the same thing?

Comment: Yes `\D*` matches anything BUT digits, i.e. your spaces and letters between those 3 groups of digits. ;-)

Comment: I have expaneded your answer with the function i am using right now

Comment: @yes123: Your answer `(\D*\d+\D*){3,}` even matches `'word1 word2 word3'` is that how you wanted it? And Basti's `(\D*\d{2,}\D*){3,}` doesn't even match string `'1 2 3'`.

Comment: Good point. I added the `\d{2,}` instead of `\d+` because of the second example `words 1 2  //> NO`. But this example failed because there are only two groups of digits, not because of only single digits. It's even possible that @yes123 wants spaces between the groups. My solution would also match `12-34-56`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$non_numeric = array_filter(
    array_filter(explode(' ', $string)),
    function($c){
        return !is_numeric($c);
    });

if(count($non_numeric)) {
    //YES
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex to make sure there are at least 3 numbers in string:

```
#(?:\b\d+\b.*?){3}#
```

**TESTING:**

```
$arr = array(
'words1 words2 111 222 333',
'words 1 2',
'words 2011 words2 2012 2013',
'1 2 3',
'1 2 ab1',);
foreach ($arr as $u) {
   echo "$u => ";
   if (preg_match('#(?:\b\d+\b.*?){3}#', $u, $m))
      var_dump($m[0]);
   else
      echo " NO MATCH\n";
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
words1 words2 111 222 333 => string(11) "111 222 333"
words 1 2 =>  NO MATCH
words 2011 words2 2012 2013 => string(21) "2011 words2 2012 2013"
1 2 3 => string(5) "1 2 3"
1 2 ab1 =>  NO MATCH
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be funny? I don't get it.

Comment: @yes123: I shortened the regex to make it more readable.

Comment: `?:` is optional here and is used for a non capturing group. `.*?` is a non-greedy or lazy way to capture a text of 0 or more length. Please see this very good reference on this: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html I am using `.*?` to capture any variable text until next `\b\d+\b` match is found.

Comment: `?:` in this case is optional but using it just speeds up things a bit. However there are some situations where use of `?:` becomes necessary to limit # of capturing groups.